# Body is accelerating non-uniformly (acceleration is increasing with displacement). How to calculate velocity & time?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, calculus

If a body is undergoing non-uniform acceleration which is increasing with displacement (It is not necessary that is directly proportional to displacement. It may be proportional to s², 1-s³, √s etc.). How is one supposed to find the velocity after traveling a certain displacement or the time required to reach there? Please explain me the process too.

(PS: Please this is not a homework problem. I really want to understand how this type of derivation is done)

Comment: You have already met a motion of the type, $\ddot x = - \omega_0\,x$ which should give you some pointers as to how to solve differential equations of this type?  

Also, $\ddot x = \dot v =\dfrac{dv}{dt} = \dfrac{dv}{dx}\cdot\dfrac{dx}{dt}= \dfrac{dv}{dx}v$, but you might reach a situation where the integrals can only be solved by numerical means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from

$$\ddot x=\frac{dv}{dt}=f(x)\\
\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x)\\
\int v\,dv=\int f(x)\,dx\quad \Rightarrow\\
\frac{v^2}{2}=\int f(x)\,dx$$

Example

$$f(x)=x^2\\
\frac{v^2}{2}=\frac{x^3}{3}\\
v=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}\,x^3}+v_0$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose acceleration $a$ is a known function of displacement $s$, so $a = f(s)$. We know that $a=\frac {dv} {dt}$. But we really want to find $\frac {dv}{ds}$ so that we can integrate this and find $v$ as a function of $s$. The way to do this is to notice that

$\displaystyle \frac {dv}{ds} = \frac {dv}{dt} \frac {dt} {ds} = \frac 1 v f(s)
\\ \Rightarrow v dv = f(s)ds
\\ \Rightarrow \int_{v(0)}^{v(s)} v dv = \int_0^s f(s) ds 
\\ \Rightarrow \frac 1 2 v(s)^2 - \frac 1 2 v(0)^2 = \int_0^s f(s) ds$

For an object with constant mass $m$ you can also derive the same relationship from an energy argument.

For example , if $f(s)=s^2$ and $v(0)=v_0>0$ then

$v(s) = \sqrt{ \frac 2 3 s^3 +v_0^2}$

Comment: Since v = ds/dt, to get the time integrate ds/v(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you plot such a velocity in a v/t diagram, the acceleration shows up as the *slope* of the curve - it's the velocity's *derivative*.

In reverse, if you plot the acceleration against time, the velocity becomes the area below the curve - it's the acceleration's *integral*.

For instance, if the acceleration increases linearly (*c* is constant), *a(t) = c * t*, the (change in) velocity is *v(t) = c * 1/2 * t^2*.

Answer (score 0):

#### Variable Acceleration Integration

- Case a) Acceleration is a function of displacement only $a(x)$, with initial conditions $t=t_0$, $x=x_0$, $v=v_0$

  $$\begin{gather}
    \tfrac{1}{2} ( v(x)^2 - v_0^2 ) = \int_{x_0}^x a(x)\,{\rm d}x \\
    t(x) -t_0 = \int_{x_0}^x \frac{1}{v(x)}\,{\rm d}x
  \end{gather}$$

  This is essentially a balance of energy, with kinetic energy on the left, and work done on the right.
- Case b) Acceleration is a function of speed only $a(v)$, with initial conditions $t=t_0$, $x=x_1$, $v=v_1$

  $$\begin{gather}
    x(v)-x_0 = \int_{v_0}^v \frac{v}{a(v)}\,{\rm d}v \\
    t(v) -t_0 = \int_{v_0}^v \frac{1}{a(v)}\,{\rm d}v
  \end{gather}$$

#### Differential Form

- Case a) Use chain rule ${\rm d}t = \tfrac{1}{v} {\rm d}x$

  $$\begin{gather} 
     {\rm d}v = a\, {\rm d}t = a\, \tfrac{1}{v} {\rm d}x \\
  v\,{\rm d}v = a\, {\rm d}x \\
  \int v\,{\rm d}v = \int a\, {\rm d}x \\
  \int {\rm d}t = \int \frac{1}{v} \,{\rm d}x
  \end{gather}$$
- Case b) Use chain rule ${\rm d}t = \tfrac{1}{a} {\rm d}v$

  $$\begin{gather} 
     {\rm d}x = v\, {\rm d}t = v\, \tfrac{1}{a} {\rm d}v \\
     \int {\rm d}x = \int \frac{v}{a}\,{\rm d}v \\
     \int {\rm d}t = \int \frac{1}{a} \,{\rm d}v
  \end{gather}$$